# Bug in GCP: Unable to change instance template for instance group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

I am trying to set a new template for an GKE instance group as proposed by [this](https://murat.io/notes/2017/logrotate-container-logs-in-google-container-engine.html) tutorial, but getting the following error:

I copied an existing template, just modified a label on it, saved it and then run:

```
$ gcloud compute instance-groups managed set-instance-template gke-some-nodepool1-1436e076-grp --template gke-some-nodepool1-7bdaa55f-1 --zone=us-east4-b
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instance-groups.managed.set-instance-template) Could not fetch resource:
 - Invalid resource usage: 'Secondary ranges specified in InstanceTemplate must be the same as already set on Instance Group Manager. Expected: sre-inception-cluster-range Actual: '.
```

It turns out that the new (cloned) template does **NOT** have the **Alias IP Ranges** field set (as does the original template).

Seems like as bug on the template copying mechanism?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using VPC-Native clusters, you'll notice that there is a "Alias IP ranges" field that does not specify a specific range. When you copy the template, rather than keeping the same value, the field is change to select a corresponding subnet. You'll have to manually change this field to match the value of the original template.

This may be a limitation of how the "copy template" function works, but it's definitely unexpected. Worth filing a case with Google support using the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)